# InputStream in java

Tags: java, file-io

How to get `InputStream` and size of `File` type in servlet?

Previously i was using `FileUpload` type which has `getInputStream()` and `getSize()` methods, but now i have to use `File` type for bulk upload. I have tried but `File` type has no such methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`File#length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) to get the size.

```
long size = file.length();
// ...
```

Use [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) constructor to create an `InputStream` based on a given `File`.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
// ...
```

See also the [`File` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and the [basic Java I/O tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).